# Как сделать, чтобы сообщение на сокетах приходило даже если пользователь не в сети python sockets?

Tags: python, сокет

Всем привет! Делаю мини чат на сокетах. Всё почти готово, но никак не могу реализовать функцию прихода сообщений, даже если пользователь не в сети.
Я могу отправить сообщение, если пользователь запустил программу и подключён на сервер, но не могу отправить когда пользователь вышел из приложения. Я хотел бы сделать как в Telegram или Whatsapp, чтобы сообщения приходили когда пользователь не был всегда в программе. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Очевидно сервер при невозможности транслировать сообщение пользователю должен хранить его у себя пока пользователь не войдет в сеть.